# How can I use Spring Security to show a div into a JSP page if the logged user have a specific role setted?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am pretty new in Spring Security and I have the following problem working on a Spring MVC application.

Into a JSP page I found this use of the Sprig Security Taglib:

```
<p class="text-right" style="font-size: 1.50em;">
    <security:authentication property="principal.ruoloSelezionato.twp1003Tiporuolo.desRuo"/>
</p>
```

that show the role of the logged user, it works fine infact in my page is printed the following output: **Utente ministeriale** that is the expected result and that represent the role of my user.

Now my problem is that, into the JSP, I have to show a text (into a `<p>...</p>`) only if the logged user have the previous role setted (**Utente ministeriale**).

How can I implement this feature? Is there some specific tag of the Spring Security Taglib that implement this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself int this way:

Inside my JSP I put the value of the specifig principal field into a variable:

```
<security:authentication property="principal.ruoloSelezionato.twp1003Tiporuolo.desRuo" var="userRole" />
```

and then I can use this value:

```
<c:out value="${userRole}"/>
```

(or inside the  tag to obtain the cconditional behavior)

Answer (score -1):

Would do this the trick for you?

```
<span sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">something</span>
```

ROLE_USER is one of the role that the user can have, change it however you see fit.

for it to work you would have to define

```
xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3"
```

Comment: No it can't work. I think that because the previous field (principal.ruoloSelezionato.twp1003Tiporuolo.desRuo) is not a true Spring Security role but only a field of the principal object (the logged user). So how can I use this property to show or not show the message?

Comment: and morever, as specified, I am not using Thymeleaf but simple JSP page

Comment: i was suggesting to do something similar to that, clearly in your context considering the different technology...
nevertheless, glad you sorted this out.